# Errors saving stacked NumPy array to text

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, csv

I am combining column data from three different input arrays into a new csv.  To do so I am using the NumPy stack function.  Right now I have a [12,3] stacked NumPy array that I am trying to export to a csv.

```
VI_Samples_v4 = numpy.stack((samplename,sample_start_date,sample_type_code), axis =1)
```

When I use the numpy save text

```
numpy.savetxt('array.csv', [VI_Samples_v4], fmt='%s', delimiter=',')
```

I get this Error: "ValueError: Expected 1D or 2D array, got 3D array instead." I am fairly certain it is a 2D array. When I ask Numpy for the array shape, I get (12,3).

```
VI_Samples_v4.shape
```

What's my error, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the square brackets you've placed around your array in the call to `numpy.savetxt`. By passing a list containing your 2D array, you're causing `numpy.savetxt` to read it as a 3D array. Just pass the array without the square brackets like so:

```
numpy.savetxt('array.csv', VI_Samples_v4, fmt='%s', delimiter=',')
```